# I am getting error in solving python exceptions

Tags: python, exception

The question is:

> Prompt the user to enter his name. The program then greets the person with his name, but if the person name is “jack” an exception is  thrown and he asked to quit the program.

I tried this:

```
import sys
try:
  name = input("Enter your name : ")
  if name == "jack":
    except NameError:
      print("Invalid Name")
      sys.exit(0)
      finally:
        print("Welcome",name)
```

And this the error I am getting.

```
File "main.py", line 5
    except NameError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You will need to re-read whatever tutorial you're reading. You'll need to be very exact about indentation in Python -- and that `name(input(...` syntax makes little sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here.
First, the line `name(input("Enter your name : "))` will raise an error because it is trying to find a function called `name` that doesn't exist. Instead use `name = input("Enter your name : ")`

---

However, that is not what is throwing this error. The real problem here is that you don't want to be using `try` or `except` at all.
What `try` `except` does is attempt to run code, and do something else if it raises an error. What your describing is trying to raise the error yourself. This is done with `raise`, for example:

```py
raise NameError("Invalid Name")
```

will give the following error:
NameError: Invalid Name
So try this code

```py
name = input("Enter your name : ")

if name == "Jack":
    raise NameError("Invalid Name")

print("Welcome", name)
```

It is worth noting that it is not using the `sys` module. This is because raising the error will exit the code automatically

Comment: Thank you so much bro

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `try`, `except` and `finally` should be on the same indentation level just like `if`, `elif` and `else` are.

Also you're missing an `=` sign in the third line, it shoul be:

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
```

In this case you should just use the `raise` keyword to raise `NameError`. You don't need `try` and `except` here.

It should be like:

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
if name == "jack":
    raise NameError("Invalid Name")
else:
    print("Welcome", name)
```

The program will quit automatically because of the exception, so you don't have to use `sys.exit` for that.